# htaccess a NGINX

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx

quiero migrar un archivo de .htaccess de Apache a NGINX, la configuracion que el .htaccess es la siguiente:

```
Options All -Indexes
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine ON

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

He intentado realizar la configuracion mediante winginx pero al pasarlas a NGINX me da error.